# jdbc ResultSet is null

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to run some updates and eventually return some resultSet which I can consume but the result is always null. My code is

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = aConnection.prepareStatement(script);
boolean results = preparedStatement.execute();
```

If my query is

```
 BEGIN                  
  Declare @MyLog as varchar(max) = '---------------------- ' 
         +  CHAR(10) + CHAR(10)              
    BEGIN         
      BEGIN TRAN    

        UPDATE MPRN SET K4101 = 'N'
        select * from HELD_FLOW

        COMMIT TRAN 

    END                  
END
```

the statement doesn't return any values. However, if my query is

```
 BEGIN                  
  Declare @MyLog as varchar(max) = '---------------------- ' 
         +  CHAR(10) + CHAR(10)              
    BEGIN         
      BEGIN TRAN    
        select * from HELD_FLOW
        UPDATE MPRN SET K4101 = 'N'


        COMMIT TRAN 

    END                  
END
```

all values are returned! So the order of update and select matters! I want to update some values first and finally return some output as in the 1st example which doesn't work...

Comment: Why `result`
 type is `boolean` ?

Comment: just checking whether result is true or false (whether there is a result set or not returned)

Comment: Adding `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the beginning of your script would probably help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute()):

> The `execute` method executes an SQL statement and indicates the form of the **first result**. You must then use the methods `getResultSet` or `getUpdateCount` to retrieve the result, and `getMoreResults` to move to any subsequent result(s).

Your procedure returns multiple results, `execute` shows you the type of first one. In first example, first result is an update count, in second one it's a result set, so you're getting `false` and `true` respectively.

You should use [`getMoreResults`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getMoreResults()) to process the remaining results and find the ResultSet.